# Hide a part of a URL with mod_rewrite but keep the argument

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I would like to write a rule where the `members/show/` string will be hidden in the URL.

The original URL: `localhost:8080/sandbox/member/show/helloworld`, where `helloworld` is the name of the account. I'd like it to be `localhost:8080/sandbox/m/helloworld`. Basically, the content delivered will be from the full url, but I'd like it to be hidden for any user.

`RewriteRule ^.*$ member/show/$0 [L,QSA]` doesn't seem to work, it throws a 500 Internal Server Error. I work with the CodeIgniter Framework, and the following rewrite rule is already present: `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`.

I tried several RewriteRule options but without success. I'd be very glad if anyone could shed some light related to my question.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(sandbox)/m/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/member/show/$2 [L,NC]
```